# Should I include "www" in my website's URLs? What are the pros and cons?

Tags: domains, url, subdomain, no-www

What are the pros and cons of having `http://www.example.com/` vs `http://example.com/`?

For example a problem I'm aware of is that if I use a domain without `www` I can't set a cookie for the current subdomain only (since there is no subdomain), and the cookies I set will be sent to all subdomains.

Comment: @John Conde: I think the edit you approved made the question worse.. "My question is fairly simple to complex and want to know the in's and outs of www vs non-www." was edited in, which is broken english and doesn't make sense in any case.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Keep in mind though that using `www.example.com` lets you to set **Cookies only on the main site**. Using `example.com` will only allow you to set cookies on `*.example.com` which includes `static.example.com`. So every request for any subdomain will include the cookies which slows down the transfer a bit. Using `www.example.com` will allow you to decide for what part you want to set cookies.

Comment: This is one of the big reasons why large websites setup completely separate domains for static content (such as http://sstatic.net for Stack Overflow) so that they have cookie-free domains. More info here: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free

Comment: yes this is the biggest downside of the "no-www" movement, by far. It is definitely annoying.

Comment: @Jeff: True to an extent, but it can be more beneficial to host static content on a different domain anyway, to increase parallelization.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: the parallelization is increased also using subdomains! http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#split

Comment: 1. If you want to create a CNAME that maps the subdomain `www.` to `example.ec2.amazonaws.com`. You can't do that with a naked domain. 2. Typing a domain name in the address bar and hitting `CTRL + ENTER` it automatically enclose the text with `http://www.` and `.com`. Having your permanent domain with a www prefix will prevent unnecessary redirection. 3. Typing in `example.com` under windows `start + run` will result in an error.

Comment: This answer is becoming obsolete now that RFC 6265 is more widely implemented. (It did not exist at the time this answer was written, though.)

Answer (score 28):

If you are going to use `www.example.com`, you should make `example.com` a permanent re-direct to `www.example.com`.

The `www` sub domain, in some cases, is actually a completely different server than the parent TLD. While most search engines are smart enough to figure that out, its still good practice to place the re-direct.

I'm the complete reverse of that, `www.example.com` is a permanent redirect to `example.com`, because I prefer using the shorter canonical URL. It also make sense to me that I can expect a HTTP request to `example.com` will yield a web page, or a redirect to whatever subdomain is dealing with HTTP requests.

Additionally, you want people linking to your site using the canonical URL, which is the one they pick out of their browser toolbar. The re-direct on the one that is NOT your canonical URL helps ensure consistency in that regard.

Comment: meaning that one should use example.com not www.example.com?

Answer (score 23):

*Including the `www` subdomain seems to boil down to two conditions:*

1. **Cookies** - Will setting cookies at `*.example.com` cause me grief (incur more traffic) because the cookies will be sent with every request, regardless of subdomain. In this case I would opt to use the `www` since it gives me the choice of setting cookies at `*.example.com` if I need it (ex. authenticated user cookie), or `www.example.com` to reduce traffic to my other subdomains.
2. **Aesthetic** - Do I care a lot about how the domain looks? If I really hate the `www` but am worried about the cookie traffic, I could alleviate the problem by hosting my static content on a whole new domain such as `static-example.com` which would remain cookie free.

Answer (score 18):

This is a minor consideration but one that is relevant for commercial sites.  There is an expectation from non-technical users that a website starts with `www` so when they don't see that they might not think of a domain as a website.

Whilst it may seem silly to those of us that know how things work I have come across this attitude frequently with family, friends and non-technical colleagues and these people are likely to represent the vast majority of your customers.

Additionally, a lot of software such as email, world processors, social networking clients & co will automatically recognise a domain name starting with `www` as a hyperlink and make it active - with a naked, or `non-www`, domain you will need to add the `http://` for the software to make it active.  Being able to click a link instead of having to copy-paste into a browser could make the difference between a customer visiting your site or going to your competitor.

Comment: Actually I see a lot of advertising for domain names without the www. For example the BBC always quote their URL as `bbc.co.uk/whatever` when they always redirect to the www version.

Comment: +1 I totally agree on your minor consideration. It's true there is definitely "an expectation from non-technical users that a website starts with www" and it's also true: "so when they don't see that they might not think of a domain as a website". It sounds odd for tech users like us, but that's life.

Comment: Typically, if the URL doesn't start with www, I include `http://` at the front.  So if the URL is `http://www.example.com`, then I often just use `www.example.com`.  If it was `http://other.example.com`, then I would use `http://other.example.com`.  Otherwise, users don't realize it is a URL.  Sounds crazy, but people mix up URLs and e-mail addresses all the time now.  Sadly, we have dumbed-down things so much on the web, that our users don't know the basics any more.

Comment: Actually, what we did was expand the reach of the internet to people who never were educated in that regard. Ten years ago, you basically only got nerds on the internet. (Exaggeration.) Nowadays almost literally everyone uses facebook, google, "the internet". How many people are out there not knowing how a car works. Or a percolator. Or typesetting. (With varying degrees of relevancy.)

Answer (score 9):

There doesn't seem to be any concrete reasons for using one over the other as far as search results or other desired outcomes. My personal preference is `no-www`, due to length.

The most important thing is to make sure you redirect to your preferred domain, and remember to set your preferred domain in Google Search Console (Google Webmaster Tools).

Answer (score 4):

Without repeating the valid answers above regarding cookies, aesthetics, non-technical users expecting the `www` subdomain etc...

Another reason I tend to favour the `www.` subdomain approach for the main site is for local development. I use `local.` for my local test server. I always expect the site to be accessed via a subdomain and can easily distinguish between the test and live sites if required. Cookies can be kept separate from the local and live sites.

- `www.example.com` Live site
- `local.example.com` Local test server

Using a subdomain for the test server also allows easy testing from a mobile device, since the subdomain can be defined in the public DNS that points to a local test server (local IP). Only when the mobile device is on the local WiFi network will it be able to access the local test server. (Make sure that mobile browser optimisations are disabled when connecting locally, otherwise the remote optimisation server will also try to access your local server and fail.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, always use `www` instead of a naked domain. Although Heroku is somewhat specialized, the kind of routing fabric they've built is likely going to become more common as people deploy websites across clusters of machines. Naked domains are just much less flexible than www because they require an A instead of a CNAME record. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords.

Although you might not think so today, every site on the web should and hopefully soon will be using SSL all the time. That's because security is always better than no security, and the costs of SSL are already only ~1% additional CPU (see http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html). You should get your SSL certificate for www as well.

Answer (score 0):

My SEO people tell me Google *doesn't like* naked domains. A symptom of this is that if you try to redirect your `myblog.blogspot.com` blog to `example.com/blog`, you will get an error that says *Blogs cannot be hosted at naked domains*.

Comment: This is very dubious.

Comment: You can't do this because Blogger hosting on a custom domain is done using [a CNAME to ghs.google.com](https://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58317), and the naked domain can't be a CNAME.