# Redirect domain address to host address with cloaking

Tags: mod-rewrite, 301-redirect, domain-forwarding, cloaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to redirect my naked domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11584/what-is-the-best-way-to-redirect-my-naked-domain)

I have purchased a domain name with hosting.

I would like visitor to my website http://www.smarttelecom.be to see only http://smarttelecom.be in their browsers address bar

What is the there a way to do this, CNAME, Domain name masking, mod_rewrite or another technique?

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect your www domain to your naked domain which is covered in this question '[What is the best way to redirect my naked domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11584/what-is-the-good-way-to-redirect-naked-domains)'