# SEO/link-juice implications of 'www.' links versus links without 'www.'

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, no-www

I remember reading ages ago that it's a good idea to choose either `www.example.com` or `domainexamplecom` as your main URL and then set the other one as a 301 redirect to point to your domain?

The reason provided was:

1. Some people may link to `www.example.com`
2. Other links may point to `example.com`

In order to not lose 'SEO link juice', the individual recommended setting up a 301 redirect from one to the other.

Has this changed? Is it true? I would have guessed that Google (and other search engines) would be smart enough to whack some code in their algorithm to understand that in most cases `www.example.com` = `example.com`?

Comment: See also: [SEO preference for WWW or HTTP:// protocol redirection? Do www websites rank better than NON-www?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11560/seo-preference-for-www-or-http-protocol-redirection-do-www-websites-rank-bet?lq=1)

Comment: Are you only interested in Google (as your last sentence implies)? Then you should add the tag [tag:google].

Comment: I'm interested in all search engines with a slight preference to Google. Hence, I'll leave it without the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason to redirect `no-www` to `www` (or the contrary) is to avoid [duplicate content](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359) issues and not to avoid losing *link juice*. If you don't apply a 301 redirect, Google is going to index both versions of your website and will identify duplicate content (bad for SEO for sure).

Moreover, you can choose 301 redirect instead of `rel="canonical"` to avoid to lose *link juice* but just few of webmasters or users will be wrong on putting your URL on their websites.

Comment: +1 for using a 301 redirect from www.example.com -> example.com. Thanks and fixed it by adding a VirtualHost in Apache. http://serverfault.com/questions/120488/redirect-url-within-apache-virtualhost

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is true and no it hasn't changed. You should set a redirect from one to the other, or use the [canonical tag](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066) to reference the canonical URL. (on this page they use an example of a URL with and without `www`).

As you mention Google is pretty smart and is usually quite good at figuring this out, but I often still see Google indexing both versions of URLs (with and without `www` prefix) when they are clearly the same page.

So you shouldn't leave it to chance and you should always make it clear which are your canonical URLs.