# www vs non-www in seo

Tags: seo, url, search-results, no-www, negative-seo

I recently overhauled a website for a client. Their preference was to switch from a www url to a non-www url as part of the redesign.

Once we launched the site, it took a major plummet in its position on SERPs. Now, I know this could be for several reasons outside of the projected issue I presented. But has anyone else ever made a similar switch and saw their website take a decline on SERPs?

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Do you redirect with a 301 header? If not, there ya go :)

Comment: You have both www and non-www properties verified in GSC and _both_ have seen a "plummet in SEO"? And by "plummet in SEO" are you solely referring to your apparent position in the SERPs? What about the number of visitors?

Comment: Whenever you make a change like this, there is a fairly significant disruption. Www versus non-www are two different sites. Martijn makes a good point. Make sure that www redirects to non-www. Otherwise, you will just have to wait. It will work out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SEO preference for www or no-www, does a site with one rank better than the other?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/11560/18400)

Comment: @marcanuy this is not exactly a duplicate of that question. That question is asking for an opinion on www vs. non-www. This one is asking for possible problem & solution they might have missed during the switch from www to non-www.

Comment: @Martijn Yes. 301 redirects are used from www to non-www.

Comment: @w3dk Yes. I am solely referring to the position in SERPs. I have updated the question to reflect this. As for visitors, based on analytics traffic appears to be on par with this time last year. However, the recent decline in positioning on SERPs just occurred so the next month or two of traffic will be more indicative.

Comment: The question being asked here: `But has anyone else ever made a similar switch and saw their website take a decline on SERPs` is what we'd consider a _polling_ question, which doesn't lead to a definitive answer, and doesn't fit well with the voting & accept format of this site (since any answer could be right). As you noted, this could also be the result of other non-specified factors, which we'd then have to try to guess at or suggest. Although the question marked as a duplicate isn't an _exact_ duplicate, some of those factors are covered there, and users are free to comment here too.