# Should OpenID clients accept adding WWW to the domain?

Tags: domains, authentication, openid

For a long time I've used OpenID delegation on my site:

`http://example.org/` delegated to: `http://example.openid-provider.com/`, so I logged into OpenID-consuming sites using the former as ID.

Recently I [added `www.` to my site's canonical domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/507/should-i-include-www-in-my-canonical-urls-what-are-the-pros-and-cons/512#512) so `http://example.org/` now redirects to `http://www.example.org/`.

**Should I be able to continue logging into existing OpenID accounts using `http://example.org/`?**

StackExchange sites say "yes". I can use either URL.

At least one other doesn't recognize my existing account.

**Who's "right" (per [spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html)) and is there anything I can fix on my end?**

Answer (score 1):

(Damn, I had to type this answer all over again because the web site design changed and locked the question.  This is getting really frustrating and wasting a lot of time.  And now, when I try to submit it, I get a blank web page with the message "Oh tin of pink meat / I ponder what you may be / Snout or ear or feet?")

How each person or organization sets up their systems is their choice.  Traditionally the third-level "www." would provide the user with access to the web site as the "A" records in DNS specify the correct host (and many administrators would configure a tiny web server at whatever host is at "example.com" to re-direct the user to "www.example.com" to keep the load off).

These days many sites have one server running multiple daemons, so the need to differentiate these hosts isn't so important anymore.