# Redirect of www vs. "all works"

Tags: apache, redirects, dns

I was asked a question from a friend if he should redirect `his-domain.com` to `www.his-domain.com`.

I answered him that it seems more intuitive to just make both work. So if you enter by `his-domain.com` you get to `his-domain.com` and if you enter `www.his-domain.com` you get to `www.his-domain.com`. This is what I do on my sites. I have an ServerAlias in my apache.conf file that says `ServerAlias my-domain.com *.my-domain.com`

But to my surprise,most major sites seems to take the redirect approach. Which I can understand if the sites are using SSL. But if they are not, I don't.

So are there any objective reasons to choose one instead of the other?

#### More nuanced edit

It would be nice if you read my question before closing it. But from the reactions I get I guess the answer could be something like:

"Don't make both www.domain.com and domain.com work side by side. Nobody does that. Just redirect one to the other".

Even if none is willing to give a technical answer to my question I would hope someone could have answered at least that instead of closing as a duplicate and refering to different question (which to some degree was related)

Comment: Also worth checking out: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/507/should-i-include-www-in-my-canonical-urls-what-are-the-pros-and-cons

Comment: Please read more than the first sentence before closing a question. The question was not about what you thought...

Comment: A more suitable closing link has been provided, without engaging into further discussion if you feel that this is a unique question and not answered anywhere else on the site in various forms please edit your question, or use the  http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/ to discuss this issue further.

Comment: Well, I reacted i little childish and don't need to go on with this :) I feel that I got some kind of answer even though my question was misunderstood (none of the other ops was asking the same question as I was). But that might be my own fault, I could have made the question more clear. Thnx...